# Laravel & laravel-dompdf page breaking shows only 1st page

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Trying to create a PDF invoice using barryvdh's laravel dompdf wrapper. I want the invoice to begin on a new page when a certain number of rows is reached. However I'm unsure on how to do it since I don't get the expected results. Here is my controller:

```
function invoice() {

        $resellerId = Input::get('resellerId');
        $startdate = Input::get('invoiceStartDate');
        $enddate = Input::get('invoiceEndDate');

        $orders = \App\order::where('reseller',1)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->where('customer_id' , $resellerId )->where('date', '>=',$startdate)->where('date', '<=',$enddate)->get();

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoicePrint',['orders' => $orders]);                    
           // $PDFOutput = $pdf->output();
           return $pdf->stream("trestaki.pdf");
}
```

And here is the relevant portion of the blade:

```
<table style="border:1px solid #000;width: 100%;">
        <tr>
        <td>
            <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Art. Nr.</span>
    </td><td> 
            <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Benämning</span>
        </td><td> 
            <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Antal</span>
    </td><td> 
            <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Pris</span>
        </td><td> 
            <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Summa</span>
        </td></tr>
    <?php $i=0; ?>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $order->order_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->getProduct->mobile }} {{ $order->getProduct->model }}</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{{ $order->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->price }}</td>
    </tr>
    <?php

    $i++;
    if($i % 25 == 0) 
        echo "<div style='page-break-after: always;'></div>";

    ?>

    @endforeach 
    <tr>
        <td colspan=5 style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <table style="width: 45%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Moms %</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Netto</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Moms</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 900;">Summa</span>
                </td>                   
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>25%</td>  
                <td>639,20</td> 
                <td>159,80</td> 
                <td>799,00</td> 
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The thing is that if I remove all the closing tags from the echo, the webpage times out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the fixed position of the main div. After removing it the page did break correctly.